# memory leak problem, destroy function is not freeing the linked list nodes created by my reverse function

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

my destroy_list(pHead1_reversed) and destroy_list(pHead2_reversed) function in my list_sum function doesn't seem to be freeing up the nodes. I'm getting a memory leak. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//add up 189 + 11

Node* head1 = NULL;
    Node* head2 = NULL;
    Node* head_sum = NULL;
    //create a list for the number 189
    head_insert(&head1, 9);
    head_insert(&head1, 8);
    head_insert(&head1, 1);
    //create a list for the number 11
    head_insert(&head2, 1);
    head_insert(&head2, 1);
    head_sum = list_sum(head1, head2);
    printf("The sum of ");
    print_list(head1);
    printf(" + ");
    print_list(head2);
    printf("\n");
    printf(" = ");
    print_list(head_sum);
    printf("\n");
    //clean up three lists
    destroy_list(head1); head1 = NULL;
    destroy_list(head2); head2 = NULL;
    destroy_list(head_sum); head_sum = NULL;
    return 0;
}
**********************************************************************
void head_insert(Node** hHead, int newItem)
{
    Node* pNode = NULL;
    pNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (pNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc failed for node \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pNode->data = newItem;
    pNode->next = *hHead;
    *hHead = pNode;
}


void destroy_list(Node* hHead)
{
    Node* current = hHead;
    Node* next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}

Node* list_sum(Node* hHead1, Node* hHead2)
{
    Node* pHead1_reversed=reverse(hHead1);
    Node* pHead2_reversed=reverse(hHead2);
    Node* result_reversed;
    Node* resultHead = NULL;
    int carry = 0;
    while (pHead1_reversed != NULL || pHead2_reversed != NULL || carry != 0) {
        int digit1 = (pHead1_reversed != NULL) ? pHead1_reversed->data : 0;
        int digit2 = (pHead2_reversed != NULL) ? pHead2_reversed->data : 0;
        int sum = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            printf("malloc failed for result node \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        newNode->data = sum % 10;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (resultHead == NULL) {
            resultHead = newNode;
        }
        else {
            Node* temp = resultHead;
            while (temp->next != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = newNode;
        }
        if (pHead1_reversed != NULL) pHead1_reversed = pHead1_reversed->next;
        if (pHead2_reversed != NULL) pHead2_reversed = pHead2_reversed->next;
    }
    destroy_list(pHead1_reversed);
    destroy_list(pHead2_reversed);
    result_reversed = reverse(resultHead);
    destroy_list(resultHead);
    return result_reversed; 
}

void print_list(Node* hHead)
{
    Node* pHead = (Node*)hHead;

    printf("*******\n");
    while (pHead != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", pHead->data);
        pHead = pHead->next;
    }
    printf("*******\n");
}



Node* reverse(Node* hHead)
{
    Node* resultHead = NULL;
    Node* next;
    while (hHead != NULL) {
        Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            printf("malloc failed for result node \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        newNode->data = hHead->data;
        newNode->next = resultHead;
        resultHead = newNode;
        hHead = hHead->next;
    }
    return resultHead;
}
```

Tried setting pHead2_reversed to NULL and it did not work. Also tried freeding the nodes directly in the reverse function instead of using the function call. The top is my main driver file and the bottom is the function implementation file.

Comment: I recommend you take out a pencil and some paper. Then draw two small lists on the paper, using labeled squares for nodes (and other variables) and arrows for the pointers/links. Then erase and redraw arrows to figure out how to solve your problem. Implement the solution once it works on paper.

Comment: And when you have problems and you need to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program, again use pencil and paper while stepping through the code in your [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to see what the code really does.

Comment: Your program is incomplete with includes of relevant headers, and type definitions.

Comment: Don't cast the void * from `malloc()`.

Comment: If you are on Linux a great tool for hunting down leaks is valgrind.

Comment: ... [-> @AllanWind] *unless* you are writing code that should be compatible for C++ as well. Relevant if you try to implement a C++ compatible header only library (otherwise the `malloc` should go into the source file anyway!), still question remains if such one should use `malloc` at all.

Comment: @Aconcagua You are correct of course but I don't think it's relevant for a question tagged c.

Comment: I created  Node* pHead2_reversed_temp = reverse(hHead2); and a Node* pHead1_reversed=pHead1_reversed_temp. I then called destroy_list(pHead2_reversed_temp) to destroy it. I know it is not pretty but it seems to work and I'm desperate.

Comment: I'm coding on visual studio and I've been using the memory snapshot tool to trace down the memory leaks. It started out as an opaque object but then I realized I didn't need to make it opaque. Hence the weird casting going on. This is has been very helpful. Thanks. I tried getting chatgpt to help but it was totally missing the pHead1_reversed = pHead1_reversed->next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're leaking memory in `list_sum`:

Although you have:

```
destroy_list(pHead1_reversed);
destroy_list(pHead2_reversed);
```

...these pointers are not pointing to the heads of these reversed lists, since you moved them forward in the preceding loop:

```
    if (pHead1_reversed != NULL) pHead1_reversed = pHead1_reversed->next;
    if (pHead2_reversed != NULL) pHead2_reversed = pHead2_reversed->next;
```

You'll have to keep a reference to these heads before looping, and then free the lists starting from those head nodes.

#### Remark

You can better avoid this from happening by defining a separate type (struct) for a linked list, which would have as member the head of the list. This would make it easier to guarantee that this head *really* is the head of the linked list. The function to free a linked list would be distinct from the function that frees a single node.

Secondly, it is not efficient if in `reverse` you have to find the end of the list *each time* to append to the result list, only to reverse that list at the end. More efficiently is to create the result in the right order immediately, by inserting the sum-digits at the *front* of the result list.

You could also destroy the reversed lists at the same time you build the sum: during that same loop. This can lead to quite elegant code.

It is also good practice to have only one function that allocates a node. Currently this code is spread in three locations.

#### Proposed code

Here is some code showing how it could be done taking the above remarks into consideration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//////////////////////// Node /////////////////////////////////

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next; 
} Node;

Node* create_node(int data, Node *next_node) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node== NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed for creating node with data %d\n", data);
        exit(1);
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->next = next_node;
    return node;
}

Node* destroy_node(Node* node) // Returns the successor
{
    Node* next = node->next;
    free(node);
    return next;
}

//////////////////////// Linked List /////////////////////////////////

typedef struct linkedlist {
    Node *head; 
} LinkedList;

LinkedList* create_list() {
    LinkedList* list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed for creating list\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

int list_is_empty(LinkedList *list) {
    return list->head ? 0 : 1;
}

int list_pop_head(LinkedList *list, int defaultValue)
{
    if (list_is_empty(list)) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    int data = list->head->data;
    list->head = destroy_node(list->head);
    return data;
}

void destroy_list(LinkedList *list)
{
    while (!list_is_empty(list)) {
        list_pop_head(list, 0);
    }
}

void list_insert_head(LinkedList *list, int data)
{
    list->head = create_node(data, list->head);
}

LinkedList* list_reverse(LinkedList* list)
{
    LinkedList *result = create_list();
    for (Node* node = list->head; node; node = node->next) {
        list_insert_head(result, node->data);
    }
    return result;
}

LinkedList* list_sum(LinkedList* list1, LinkedList* list2)
{
    LinkedList* reversed1 = list_reverse(list1);
    LinkedList* reversed2 = list_reverse(list2);
    LinkedList* result = create_list();
    int carry = 0;
    
    while (!list_is_empty(reversed1) || !list_is_empty(reversed2) || carry) {
        int sum = list_pop_head(reversed1, 0) + list_pop_head(reversed2, 0) + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        list_insert_head(result, sum % 10);
    }
    return result;
}

void list_print(LinkedList* list)
{
    for (Node* node = list->head; node; node = node->next) {
       printf("%d -> ", node->data);
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //add up 189 + 11
    LinkedList* list1 = create_list();
    LinkedList* list2 = create_list();
    //populate a list for the number 189
    list_insert_head(list1, 9);
    list_insert_head(list1, 8);
    list_insert_head(list1, 1);
    //populate a list for the number 11
    list_insert_head(list2, 1);
    list_insert_head(list2, 1);
    LinkedList *head_sum = list_sum(list1, list2);
    printf("The sum of\n");
    list_print(list1);
    printf("+\n");
    list_print(list2);
    printf("=\n");
    list_print(head_sum);
    //clean up three lists
    destroy_list(list1);
    destroy_list(list2);
    destroy_list(head_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `list_pop_head()` returning 0 on an empty list allows for clean implementation of `list_sum()` but it's an error prune design to have overlapping value and error domains.  If op needs to implement multiplication then the identity value is no longer 0 but 1 and you need to check with `list_is_empty()` and introduce asymmetry compared to sum.  It's ok to design for now and change the design in the future if needed.

Comment: @AllanWind, point taken. Updated to include an argument for this default value.

Comment: Good change but in general this requires caller to know which value stored to determine a suitable separate error value.  This may be fine especially for this use case.  It would be better to separate the two domains.  For example return the error and use an out parameter for the value (or the opposite, or tagged union that either returns an error or value etc).

Comment: *"this requires caller to know which value stored to determine a suitable separate error value."*: yes, and I cannot see why the caller would *not* know which value they want to get as a default. So I see no problem here. I intended the pop feature to always return an integer, and not to consider an empty stack as an error condition for the pop to function. On the contrary, I consider here the call on an empty stack to be an intentional feature. If we want to have a pop function where it is considered an error when done on an empty list, then yes, it would be better to have a different design.

Comment: I would let the caller generate the default instead of list (as it co-mingles two things) but you are absolute right that it's a good change to have caller control the default value.  It's your specification so it's ok to have `pop` either return and element or a default value.  To me `pop` is a stack operation and underflow is an error.  Single linked list is concrete data structure and didn't find a authoritative source for it's operation.   Not asking you to make any changes, btw, just adding a bit of context.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to address the memory leak in `list_sum()` is to reverse the list in-place.  If you change `head_insert()` to take a `Node *` and return the newly allocated node it becomes a more general function.  Then you can reuse `head_insert()` in `list_sum()`, use the fact that `head_insert()` reverse the list for you and combine the two duplicate NULL checks.  For good measure use `signed char` instead of `int` and shorter variable names:

```
Node *head_insert(Node *hHead, int newItem) {
    Node* pNode = malloc(sizeof *pNode);
    if (!pNode) {
        printf("malloc failed for node \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pNode->data = newItem;
    pNode->next = hHead;
    return pNode;
}

Node* reverse(Node* hHead) {
    if(!hHead)
        return hHead;
    Node *next = hHead->next;
    hHead->next = NULL;
    while(next) {
        Node *prev = hHead;
        hHead = next;
        next = hHead->next;
        hHead->next = prev;
    }
    return hHead;
}

Node *list_sum(Node* a, Node* b) {
    a = reverse(a);
    b = reverse(b);
    Node* result = NULL;
    signed char carry = 0;
    for(Node *a2 = a, *b2 = b; a2 || b2 || carry; ) {
        signed char a2_digit = 0;
        if(a2) {
            a2_digit = a2->data;
            a2 = a2->next;
        }
        signed char b2_digit = 0;
        if(b2) {
            b2_digit = b2->data;
            b2 = b2->next;
        }
        signed char sum = a2_digit + b2_digit + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        result = head_insert(result, sum % 10);
    }
    reverse(a);
    reverse(b);
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    //add up 189 + 11
    Node* head1 = NULL;
    Node* head2 = NULL;
    Node* head_sum = NULL;
    //create a list for the number 189
    head1 = head_insert(head1, 9);
    head1 = head_insert(head1, 8);
    head1 = head_insert(head1, 1);
    //create a list for the number 11
    head2 = head_insert(head2, 1);
    head2 = head_insert(head2, 1);
    head_sum = list_sum(head1, head2);
    printf("The sum of ");
    print_list(head1);
    printf(" + ");
    print_list(head2);
    printf(" = ");
    print_list(head_sum);
    printf("\n");
    //clean up three lists
    destroy_list(head1);
    destroy_list(head2);
    destroy_list(head_sum);
}
```

and example run via `valgrind --leak-check=full` (I removed `\n` in `print_list()` to make the output more compact):

```
The sum of 189 + 11 = 200
[...]
==3546== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3546==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3546==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 1,152 bytes allocated
==3546== 
==3546== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: Exactly.  Pro tip: In software it's nearly free to try things out.

Comment: I checked trincot's answer because I have to use head_insert(Node** hHead, int newItem). Thanks a lot though.

Comment: @cougarhound yes?

Comment: Nevermind I just noticed that he also did not use head_insert(Node** hHead, int new Item). Not sure what I was talking about.

Comment: You can implement the original `head_insert()` in terms of the one I posted (but not the other way around).  Make sure you state those requirements upfront so I answers are helpful to you.  My answer, btw, is the only one that provide proof of fix of the leak.